# OpenPGP signing with BouncyCastle giving incomplete message

Tags: java, php, android, bouncycastle, openpgp

I am trying to implement OpenPGP signing of a byte array (could also be a string, shouldn't be important as the source is JSON) but I'm getting erroneous output from the Java BouncyCastle implementation. I was testing with and am wanting to emulate gnupg's --sign option. Here is the code I modified from the example usage:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.SignatureException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.bouncycastle.bcpg.BCPGOutputStream;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPCompressedData;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPCompressedDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPLiteralData;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPLiteralDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPrivateKey;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKey;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKeyRing;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKeyRingCollection;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSignature;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSignatureGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSignatureSubpacketGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPUtil;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcaPGPContentSignerBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcePBESecretKeyDecryptorBuilder;

public class OpenPGP {

private static PGPSecretKey readSecretKey(final InputStream input)
        throws IOException, PGPException {
    final PGPSecretKeyRingCollection pgpSec = new PGPSecretKeyRingCollection(
            PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(input));

    final Iterator keyRingIter = pgpSec.getKeyRings();
    while (keyRingIter.hasNext()) {
        final PGPSecretKeyRing keyRing = (PGPSecretKeyRing) keyRingIter
                .next();

        final Iterator keyIter = keyRing.getSecretKeys();
        while (keyIter.hasNext()) {
            final PGPSecretKey key = (PGPSecretKey) keyIter.next();

            if (key.isSigningKey())
                return key;
        }
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Can't find signing key in key ring.");
}

public static byte[] sign(final byte[] data, final String key)
        throws IOException, PGPException, SignatureException {
    PGPSecretKey pgpSec;

    pgpSec = readSecretKey(new ByteArrayInputStream(key.getBytes()));

    PGPPrivateKey pgpPrivKey;

    pgpPrivKey = pgpSec
            .extractPrivateKey(new JcePBESecretKeyDecryptorBuilder()
                .setProvider("BC").build("".toCharArray()));

    final PGPSignatureGenerator sGen = new PGPSignatureGenerator(
            new JcaPGPContentSignerBuilder(pgpSec.getPublicKey()
                    .getAlgorithm(), PGPUtil.SHA1).setProvider("BC"));

    sGen.init(PGPSignature.BINARY_DOCUMENT, pgpPrivKey);

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    final Iterator it = pgpSec.getPublicKey().getUserIDs();
    if (it.hasNext()) {
        final PGPSignatureSubpacketGenerator spGen = new PGPSignatureSubpacketGenerator();

        spGen.setSignerUserID(false, (String) it.next());
        sGen.setHashedSubpackets(spGen.generate());
    }

    final PGPCompressedDataGenerator compressDataGenerator = new PGPCompressedDataGenerator(
            PGPCompressedData.ZLIB);
    final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final BCPGOutputStream bOut = new BCPGOutputStream(
            compressDataGenerator.open(out));

    sGen.generateOnePassVersion(false).encode(bOut);

    final PGPLiteralDataGenerator lGen = new PGPLiteralDataGenerator();
    OutputStream lOut;
    lOut = lGen.open(bOut, PGPLiteralData.BINARY, "score.dat", new Date(),
            data);

    final InputStream fIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    int ch;

    while ((ch = fIn.read()) >= 0) {
        lOut.write(ch);
        sGen.update((byte) ch);
    }

    lGen.close();

    sGen.generate().encode(bOut);
    compressDataGenerator.close();
    return out.toByteArray();
}
}
```

Now the result of the sign function is base64 encoded then made safe for urls and seems to be of an appropriate length but upon decoding the message is invalid. Here is an example of what is decoded:

```
0:
    version: 3
    signature_type: 0
    hash_algorithm: 2
    key_algorithm: 1
    key_id: 4F65C291695F46BA
    nested: 0
    tag: 4
    size: <NULL>
    data: <NULL>
```

That is a pretty printed PHP object from my port of an older php openpgp lib to newer standards, it's on github @ mudhairless/openpgp and is the result of

```
\OpenPGP\Message::parse($message);
```

The key_id there is correct but the message differs from the gnupg generated message greatly, missing the actual data:

```
0:
    0:
        version: 3
        signature_type: 0
        hash_algorithm: 2
        key_algorithm: 1
        key_id: 4F65C291695F46BA
        nested: 1
        tag: 4
        size: <NULL>
        data: <NULL>

    1:
        format: b
        filename: data.txt
        timestamp: 1400821038
        tag: 11
        size: 12
        data: 1234567890

    2:
        version: 4
        signature_type: 0
        hash_algorithm: 2
        key_algorithm: 1
        hashed_subpackets:
            0:
                tag: 2
                size: <NULL>
                data: 1400821038


        unhashed_subpackets:
            0:
                tag: 16
                size: <NULL>
                data: 4F65C291695F46BA


        hash_head: 51977
        trailer: S~�.�
        tag: 2
        size: <NULL>
        data:
            0: <long string of random characters>
```

I've done quite a bit of searching on this issue and haven't had any luck so any assistant would be appreciated.